# log in user when it's a nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey I have a company and user model, where user belongs_to company and the company accepts nested attributes for the user. That's how the user registers.

However I'm trying to make the user log in successfully when it's been created, but I'm unable to get the user params.

Here's my companies create controller:

```
def create
  @company = Company.new(company_params)
  if @company.save
    log_in params[:company][:user]
    flash[:success] = "You've successfully registered an account"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

and my helper method is:

```
def log_in(user)
 session[:user_id] = user.id
end
```

the error I get is:

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

and the request parameters are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"fcIJb",
 "company"=>{"users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"john doe",
 "email"=>"john@bluth.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}},
 "name"=>"Bluth Company"},
 "commit"=>"Create Company"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`params[:company][:user]` is not a user object, it's just a hash of user characteristics... and a hash that doesn't exit (the actual hash is `[:company][:users_attributes]`)

So a better solution would be to retrieve the user record (where the id lives)...

```
log_in @company.users.first
```

Comment: Yeah I actually thought about doing that, but for some reason it kinda feels wrong? I guess it's because it gets the first user of the company, which obviously will be the user that creates it thus this user, but it doesn't really mean THIS user per se. If I'm making myself understood?

Comment: Yes, but in "create" `first` user is always `this` user so that's fine.  The situation would be different under `edit` but I don't imagine you have an auto-login for edit conditions.  This is the way I'd do it, it feels ok to me. :)